# Существительное глажка, утюжка

Tags: определение

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно называется процесс обработки белья утюгом: глажка, глажение или утюжка? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно словарям, белье можно гладить и утюжить, а сам процесс  имеет несколько названий: глажение, глаженье и глажка, а также утюжение и утюжка.

С точки зрения частотности употребления "глажение, глаженье и глажка" употребляются одинаково часто, реже используется "утюжка", и практически не используется "утюжение".

Comment: София, Вы, как всегда, оперативно приходите на помощь))). Спасибо Вам большое за развернутое объяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Глажка - дома.
А в технологическом процессе, на предприятии,  в швейном производстве есть разные действия: заутюжить, разутюжить и др.
Утюжка - профессионально.

Comment: Опечатки должны остаться дома.