# Этимология слова "утюг"

Tags: этимология

С точки зрения носителя РЯ-ка, УТЮГ – это о-тяг-ощение (пресс).
Можно допустить версию «рас-тяж-ение» мятого материала (субстанции) посредством орудия «утюг».
Однако и Фасмер, и Шанский склоняются к версии «гладить», через заимствование из ТЯ-ков. 
Очевидно, что объем словарной статьи не дает возможности полноценно аргументировать выбор версии происхождения слова. Какими доводами можно восполнить этот «вынужденный пробел» в вышеупомянутых словарях по отношению к слову УТЮГ?

[Полезная ссылка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35354/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: С точки зрения «носителя РЯ-ка» писать так уважительно по отношению к языку?

Answer (score 4):

**Слово "утюг"** отмечено в русском языке с начала XVII века, оно тюркского происхождения, сравнить: utu (турец.) - утюг.  Есть предположение, что **значение корня  ot/ut** -  "проходить сквозь, через, мимо".

Также предполагают, что **конечное "к" на конце слова (а тем более "г")**   возникло на русской почве, а затем распространилось в части тюркских языков (влияние слов "круг", "плуг").

Материал из словаря Черных.

Comment: Фасмер говорит об исходном Г ([ɣ]) в тюркских. Черных опять оригинальничает? Да и обратный переход в языки источники фонетического наращения - это тоже "свежо".

Answer (score 1):

> . Однако, и Фасмер, и Шанский склоняются к версии «гладить», через
>   заимствование из ТЯ-ков.

Меня вполне устраивает эта версия. Никаких пробелов не наблюдаю.
Тут еще такой момент. Если уж Шанский и Фасмер сошлись, можете не сомневаться.

> род. п. -а́, утю́жить. Из тюрк. *ütüɣ, тур. ütü – то же; см. Мi. ТЕl.
>   2, 183; ЕW 372; Корш, AfslPh 9, 677; ИОРЯС 8, 4, 42; Локоч 167.

Вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Слово делится на два значения , Ут что в переводе с татарского означает Огонь/раскалённое/уголёк/электричество...  И вторая половина Юг это слово правильно произносится Тык ,что в переводе означает Положи/воткни/засунь... Первые Утюги как известно , были Железными и двух видов, один утюг клали в огонь , тем самым нагревая его , а второй имел крышку , тем самым открывая крышку люди клали туда уголёк! От этих последовательностей татары и назвали эту вещь Ут тык !